# Angular ngStyle runs endlessly even though no change to model happening

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a problem with `ngStyle` which seemingly runs endlessly, even though no changes are happening behind the scenes to component.

This is a basic app that loads 3D object into the app and positions them with some random parameters for realistic effect:

```
        <ng-container>
          <app-inventory-model
            [item]="loadedItem"
            [ngStyle]="renderItem(loadedItem.weight, index)"
          ></app-inventory-model>
        </ng-container>
```

And controller:

```
  renderItem(w: number, index) {
    let baseHeight = 20;
    index++;
    return {
      zoom: `${w}`,
      transform: `
        translateZ(${w * baseHeight * index}px)
        translateX(${randomNumFromMax(6)}px)
        translateY(${randomNumFromMax(6)}px)
        `
    };
  }
```

Here is a quick demo of what is happening:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/os6tb.jpg

What is the best course of action for this use case? I don't want to hardcode a bunch of CSS, would rather do it dynamically. Should I isolate this to a separted component and look into adjusting change detection strategy for said component?

Thank you, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should use a pure pipe in your case instead of a method call (if you want it to run only when `loadedItem.weight` and `index` change.

Answer (score 3):

It happens because you are using a method in your template. So your method will be executed in each event on the view, which can be a lot of times. It could be a big problem of performance.

Try to avoid methods in your template, instead use variables.

You can read more about [When not to use methods in templates](https://blog.appverse.io/why-it-is-a-bad-idea-to-use-methods-in-the-html-templates-with-angular-2-30d49f0d3b16)